# Parsing XML from PHP webservice call with jQuery: Is 'https' enough to secure the XML?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, https

Here's my situation:

I've successfully created a simple PHP webservice to pull data from MySQL. I've got an HTML page with jQuery making an AJAX call to that webservice. The PHP returns XML, which the jQuery parses and displays on success. Pretty standard stuff here.

I've done a lot of research on securing the XML during transit to the HTML page. I'm not passing sensitive info, however I don't like the idea that the info is just out there for the taking during transit. I was considering making all the calls using https and securing the webservice folder. Does anyone know if this is enough to secure the data? I feel like it should be...

Also, this type of webservice could eventually be consumed by an iPhone APP, if that has any bearing on the response or direction of answers here. Thoughts?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: If it's not sensitive data, why be concerned about people sniffing the traffic?

Comment: Good question. It's information that i've gone through the trouble of gathering, and would rather not just "give it away" all nice and pretty. Plus it seems like good practice to just plan on securing these types of services when possible.

Comment: You'd only be `giving it away` to someone sitting in an ISP or NSP sniffing traffic.. I doubt someone taking that kind of risk is going to find your information as profitable as Credit Card numbers, SSNs, etc.

Comment: @jnpcl: You've got a point. I'm just overly-paranoid, which isn't necessarily a bad trait when you're a developer!

Comment: I would normally agree, but when it creates extra work and overhead for your code, it seems like it's a waste. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your users need to authenticate when using the webservice and this is done over https and transmitting the xml is done over https as well. That part of the transmission is secure and can not be sniffed.

If you connect to your mysql server on a private network or block external access to the mysql server as well then all should be secure (insecure scripting not taken into consideration)

Comment: At this point I'm not requiring any user authentication, since we're talking about just returning information from a MySQL DB search query performed by the PHP webservice. That confirms my suspicion that HTTPS would be enough to secure this type of simple communication. The answers found in most posts on this site (or Google) yield answers like "impossible" or "can't be done." I found that pretty strange when HTTPS seemed like a solid, obvious solution.

Comment: Follow-up question: Does anyone know that if you are using jQtouch and eventually decide to wrap it up for an iPad app, if you can still make https calls to your webservice without any help from xcode? I'd imagine that the https call won't work once its in "app" form, since there's no way to secure the app itself on a user's phone without xcode calls. Any ideas?